# Angular primeNG Calendar object needs to be a millisecond timestamp

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I need some help, I can't seem to figure this out.

I need my date object to be a millisecond object that is being passed and not the format with

I've tried almost everything. and I cannot get my object into milliseconds (which I need for my backend JSON object)

any suggestions will help, thanks.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <h3>Icon</h3>
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date4" [showIcon]="true" dateFormat="@" ></p-calendar> <span style="margin-left:35px">{{date4}}</span>
  </div>
```

**.TS**

```
 date4: Date;
```

**Current: Output**

```
Wed Feb 07 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

**Also Tried**

```
date4 = new Date(this.date4).getTime();
```

I tried this as well but still showing:

Comment: `I've tried almost everything`, namely?

Answer (score 0):

Transform the date into milliseconds :

```js
let ms = new Date("Wed Feb 07 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)").getTime()

console.log(ms)
```

Comment: sorry, I was a bit vague there, excuse my ignorance. You are passing in string of the Date output. What is the proper way of taking the Date: date4; and passing that into the .getTime()?

Comment: date4: string;
  ms = new Date(this.date4).getTime();    ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks.

```
date4: Date;
ms = new Date(this.date4).getTime();


onClick(){
this.ms = new Date(this.date4).getTime();
console.log(this.ms);
```

}